# convert audio to lower sampling rate

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, audio-recording

I am using `AVRecorder` to save recording and `AVAssetExportsession` to append multiple files. But output of the `Exportsession` is too large.

So I would like to convert it to a lower size before uploading it to the server. How can I convert this to a lower sampling rate.

Answer (score 2):

Use `AVAssetWriter` (Apple docs: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAssetWriter_Class/index.html), which will allow you to choose bitrate/channel/etc options for the file.

This related question ([AVAssetWriter How to write down-sampled/compressed m4a/mp3 files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13056978/avassetwriter-how-to-write-down-sampled-compressed-m4a-mp3-files)) has a full code sample using `AVAssetWriter` if you need that -- be sure, of course, to take note of the answer to that question, in regards to locations for the exported file.